# LVL public key Location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, base64, android-lvl, apk-expansion-files

I've followed the tutorial of this link:

[Google Play OBB Downloader Tutorial](http://www.exoa.fr/tutorial-unity-4-apk-splitting-google-play-obb/).

But I don't know about LVL Public Key.

Where is the LVL Public Key Location?
Does the LVL public key have the same key as the Base64 publickKey?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. LVL public key is base64 public key. They are the same.